# How can I directly go to an action in the browser?

Tags: yii2

I have a custom contorller called `A1Controller` which has an action called `actionGetdetails`. How do I go to this action in the browser? I tried `http://localhost/Yii2basicapp/web/a1/getdetails`, but it doesn't work.
This is my setting in the web.php file

```
`'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
       'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'a1'],
                 ],
            ],`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii expects camelcase actions to be rendered with dashes, so you should access it like `http://localhost/Yii2basicapp/web/a1/get-details`

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a rest full browser add on to access the rest controller action to work as rest client for You
I use [Rest Client Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rest-easy/) for Firefox You can search for alternative for Your favorite browser